# How to make a bootstrap website compatible to IE9 browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had design a website using bootstrap, jquery, css3 and html5. The problem where I am getting is what ever the design I had designed to the website it is not working with IE9 browser, But site is perfectly works with chrome and firefox. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

You can check the website at www.techieez.com/sea

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is a Bootstrap issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Add this between your head tag.

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Did you gone through link which I had provided above

Comment: Please check the link and try to provide the solution which is copatible